# Criptografia em C - Cifra de César

Tags: c

Boa tarde,

Estou desenvolvendo um código de criptografia básica (Cifra de César) em C.

Estou usando a lógica de percorrer 2 vetores: vetTexto e vetLetras, onde ocorre a comparação do **char** e posteriormente substitui-lo 3 posições a frente no vetLetras, porém não estou tendo sucesso. O código compila, mas na hora de rodar fica pedindo entradas do texto a ser criptografado várias vezes (entradas maiores do que o tamanho do vetor estipulado por mim).

Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>   

int main (){

#define tamanhoTexto 4
#define qtdLetras 26

int i = 0, j = 0;
char vetTexto[tamanhoTexto];
char vetLetras[26] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

for(i=0; i<tamanhoTexto;i++){  //Lendo o texto a ser encriptado
scanf ("%c", &vetTexto[tamanhoTexto]);
}

for (i = 0; i < tamanhoTexto; i++){ //Varrendo os 2 vetores fazendo a busca de letras correspondentes
  for (j = 0; j < qtdLetras; j++){

      if(vetTexto[i] == vetLetras[j] && j+ 3 <qtdLetras){ //j+3(deslocamento) não pode sair do vetor letras

          vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[j+ 3];
      }else{ 

          j = j + 3;
          j = j - qtdLetras; //caso saia, faço a soma e tiro 26, pra voltar ao começo.
          vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[j];
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tamanhoTexto; i++){ //impressão do texto criptografado

  printf ("%c", vetTexto[i]);
}
  return 0;
}
```

Já vi algumas perguntas semelhantes aqui no fórum, mas estão usando uma lógica e sintaxe diferente da minha.

Sendo um pouco mais objetivo: as minhas dúvidas são:

- Por quê o código não funciona?
- A lógica está correta?
- Existe uma forma melhor de aplicar esse tipo de criptografia em C?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Olá, tudo bem. Eu já fiz esse algoritmo em php, se quiser dar uma olhada... https://github.com/flhorizonte/caesar-cipher-algorithm/blob/master/CifraCesar.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Primeiro problema

```
for(i=0; i<tamanhoTexto;i++){  //Lendo o texto a ser encriptado
scanf ("%c", &vetTexto[tamanhoTexto]);
}
```

Ao invés de `&vetTexto[tamanhoTexto]` era para ser `&vetTexto[i]`.

### Segundo problema

```
            j = j + 3;
            j = j - qtdLetras; //caso saia, faço a soma e tiro 26, pra voltar ao começo.
            vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[j];
```

Não altere as variáveis que servem como contador do laço, estando do lado de dentro dele. Isso daí acaba criando um loop infinito! Use isso:

```
            int k = j + 3;
            if (k > qtdLetras) k = k - qtdLetras; //caso saia, faço a soma e tiro 26, pra voltar ao começo.
            vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[k];
```

Ou simplificando isso:

```
            vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[(j + 3) % qtdLetras];
```

### Terceiro problema

Observe o `if`. Ele tem que entrar se as letras dos dois laços forem a mesma e ele não ultrapassar o Z. No caso contrário ele entra no `else`. Entretanto, ele deveria entrar no `else` apenas se ele ultrapassar o Z, mas ainda sendo o caso de letras iguais, mas ele entra no `else` também quando as letras são diferentes. O certo seria então colocar assim:

```
  if (vetTexto[i] == vetLetras[j]) {
      if (j + 3 < qtdLetras) {
          vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[j + 3];
      } else {
          vetTexto[i] = vetLetras[(j + 3) % qtdLetras];
      }
  }
```

### Primeira otimização

Você não precisa declarar o vetor `vetLetras`. Basta ver que, para qualquer `x` entre 0 e 25, `vetLetras[x]` tem o valor de `'A' + x`. Assim, você pode substituir todas as ocorrências de `vetLetras[...]` por essa fórmula e com isso eliminar o vetor `vetLetras`.

### Segunda otimização

Uma vez que você pode usar o `% qtdLetras` ao atribuir um valor ao `vetTexto[i]`, você não precisará mais do `if` interno, pois com essa operação do `else`, tanto faz se ele ultrapassou ou não o Z, ele vai ficar correto.

### Convenções de código

Para deixar o código mais alinhado com as convenções da linguagem, utilize `LETRAS_MAIÚSCULAS` para constantes e coloque as `#define`s antes do `main`. E também idente o seu código. Sugiro também mudar `vetTexto` para apenas `texto`.

### Quarto problema

Seu código deve estar assim:

```
for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < QTD_LETRAS; j++) {
        if (texto[i] == 'A' + j) texto[i] = 'A' + (j + 3) % QTD_LETRAS;
    }
}
```

Você varre os dois vetores para fazer a substituição, mas esse `if` só vai entrar quando `j` for igual a `texto[i] - 'A'`. Nesse caso, você não precisa mais do laço interno, que fica assim:

```
for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
    j = texto[i] - 'A';
    texto[i] = 'A' + (j + 3) % QTD_LETRAS;
}
```

E isso por sua vez é reduzido para isso:

```
for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
    texto[i] = 'A' + (texto[i] - 'A' + 3) % QTD_LETRAS;
}
```

A variável `j` torna-se então desnecessária.

### Código completo

O seu código completo revisado fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAMANHO_TEXTO 4
#define QTD_LETRAS 26

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    char texto[TAMANHO_TEXTO];

    for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &texto[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
        texto[i] = 'A' + (texto[i] - 'A' + 3) % QTD_LETRAS;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
        printf("%c", texto[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/oBfpjq) Com a entrada `ABXY`, ele produz a saída `DEAB`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Victor!
Poderia me tirar outra dúvida? eu entendi a fórmula final, mas não entendi o passo a passo lógico para chegar até o trecho de comparação e substituição, poderia me explicar?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < TAMANHO_TEXTO; i++) {
    texto[i] = 'A' + (texto[i] - 'A' + 3) % QTD_LETRAS;

Comment: @H.Lima `texto[i]` é a letra. Assim sendo, `texto[i] - 'A'` vai ser 0 para A, 1 para B, 2 para C, ... 25 para Z. Somando 3 nisso, temos que A vai para 3, B para 4, ... Z para 28. Aplicando o `% QTD_LETRAS`, o que vai acontecer é que um número entre 3 e 25 (que é do C ao W) após o `% 26` vai ficar igual. Já com o X, Y e Z (que são 26, 27 e 28), vão mudar para 0, 1 e 2. Depois disso tudo, o `A +` pega esses números (A->3, ..., W->25, X->0, ..., Z->2) e transforma em (A->D, ... W->Z, X->A, ..., Z->C). Isso é atribuído ao `texto[i]` encriptando então o texto.

Comment: Agora entendi, não tinha percebido que esse trecho estava atribuindo valores numéricos às letras, Obrigado novamente!

Answer (score -2):

voce precisa da biblioteca do cc50 para compilar, pode encontrar ela aqui:
https://github.com/GabrielRCL/CC50/tree/main/Semana%202/lib

use o comando para compilar:

```
gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Wformat=0 -o caesar caesar.c -lcc50 -lm
```

SCRIPT:

```
 #include <cc50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h> //use this library to use "atoi()"
    
    //CIFRA DE CESAR - CRIPTOGRAFIA
    // FORMULA: Ci = ( Pi + k ) % 26
    // Ci = igésimo caractere criptografado
    // P = Frase para criptografar (string inserida)
    // Pi = igésimo caractere referente a String
    
    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[])    //char * = string
    {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);  // k é o valor que o humano inserir no argumento transformado em inteiro
    
        char A = 'A';   // Int A = 65
        char a = 'a';   // Int a = 97
    
        printf("Insira o texto para criptografar: \n");
        string p = GetString();
    
    //   === [Criptografando] ===
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (p[i] == 32) {
                //ESPAÇO - FIX BUG
                printf("%c", p[i]);
    
            } else if (p[i] < 97) {
                //LETRA MAIUSCULA
                int Pi = p[i] - ( (int)A - 1 ); //transformando para inteiro e subtraindo 64 para deixar o A = 1 / B = 2 / C = 3
                int Ci = ( ( Pi + k ) % 26 ) + ( (int)A - 1 );  //adicionando 64 para voltar aos valores normais de char A = 65 / B = 66 / C = 67
                printf("%c", Ci);
    
            } else {
                //LETRA MINUSCULA
                int Pi = p[i] - ( (int)a - 1 ); //transformando para inteiro e subtraindo 64 para deixar o a = 1 / b = 2 / c = 3
                int Ci = ( ( Pi + k ) % 26 ) + ( (int)a - 1 );  //adicionando 96 para voltar aos valores normais de char A = 97 / B = 98 / C = 99
                printf("%c", Ci);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
    }
```